# Hibernate returns 'The database returned no natively generated identity value' error when INSERT IGNORE statement does nothing

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hibernate returns the 'The database returned no natively generated identity value' error whenever my INSERT IGNORE statements fail because of duplicate values. However everything works just fine on other insertions, and even when it fails with an error the internal id is incremented (e.g. first insertion gets id 1, then I get a failure, then I try to insert something else and it gets id 3).

Here's the Java entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@With
@ToString
@Table(name = "commission_warning", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"commission_id", "type"})})
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO commission_warning (commission_id, type) VALUES (?, ?)")
public class CommissionWarning {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private final Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private final Commission commission;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final CommissionWarningType type;
}
```

MySQL Workbench generates the following CREATE statement to replicate the table, and everything seems fine to me:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `commission_warning` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UKbffm7pdogka4homn1e47fasw` (`commission_id`,`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKtg3yujdt6esjrwmer7cdsyalw` FOREIGN KEY (`commission_id`) REFERENCES `commission` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Any idea what could cause the ignored statements to cause such an error? Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not fully understand the question! Insert ignore should not return a generated id if it fails because of duplicate entry value. It will return nothing. This should work well in mysql client. However, this may not work well in an ORM, which expects either an error or a new row to be be created.

Comment: The issue indeed appears when using an ORM. Is there a workaround or should I use another system entirely?

Comment: Use plain old insert without the ignore part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I found out that REPLACE instead of INSERT IGNORE does the trick. I would have preferred avoiding the extra DELETE query associated with REPLACE but it should be an acceptable solution for my case.